# Brother MFC-J825DW printer only printing some colors

Tags: printer, brother-printer

I think I left my printer turned off for too long (over a week). When I tried to use it again today, it was not printing properly. Here is what the printer test page looks like:

[image]

Here is what it is supposed to look like:

[image]

As you can see, only a little yellow is showing, and barely any black.

I tried replacing the black cartridge, and I also ran the cleaning cycle a few times with no luck. I did use aftermarket inks. Could that be the issue?

Is my printer toast or can it be salvaged?

Comment: Before you say it is toast, invest in some official Brother branded cartridges, there is a difference. The print head on most cartridges is built into the cartridge itself and many cartridges are just refills of OEM or third party empties. If a new, original cartridge fails, replace it with a laser printer, you can get a quality color MFC laser for about the same price you paid for that ink jet unit and it will last 100x longer, even if it doesn't get used for 6 months (toner doesn't dry out, the bain of inkjet printers).

Comment: This model doesn't have the print heads on the cartridges.

Comment: Is the print head removable? Remove it from the printer and soak the end of it in 90%+ isopropyl alcohol perhaps?

Comment: Here is the service manual: http://support.brother-usa.com/Virdata/Content/en-US/MFC/Technical/ServiceManual/SM_MFC_J280W_J425W_J430w_J435W_J625DW_J825DW_J835DW_EN_5063.PDF See page 3-36. It is very complicated. Is it worth taking it to have it serviced? The service manual says drying can cause damage to the head. I assume they mean permanent damage.

Comment: Yeah, this one looks a little tougher than many I have worked on... Could say you have nothing to lose though.

Comment: Black seems to be working again. I guess I can live without yellow.